# Finding a set of specific neighboring points (not the whole of them) given two different 3D points

Tags: java, 3d

I'll try to explain my problem: I'm working with a 3D environment, I have two adjacent points (for example A: 1,1,1 and B: 2,1,1) and I need a method to find all 8 or 6 points that are neighboring to B. I can do this on paper but I cannot find a way to do this in the program, unless I specify it point by point manually (pretty annoying and long since it's 18*8 + 8*6 different cases).

I did the calculations by hand and the results are in my example: 
2,1,0; 2,2,0; 2,0,1; 2,0,2; 2,1,2; 2,2,1; 2,2,2; 2,0,0

Another example has A: 1,1,1 and B: 2,2,1 with the following results:
2,1,1; 1,2,1; 2,1,2; 1,2,2; 2,1,0; 1,2,0; 2,2,2; 2,2,0

A third one would be A: 1,1,1 and B 2,2,2:
2,2,1; 2,1,2; 1,2,2; 1,1,2; 1,2,1; 2,1,1

Comment: When is it 6 neighbours?  Also, it's not clear what the relevance of A is here, can you draw a (2D) diagram?

Comment: What is the relevance of A if you are trying to find all points that are neighbors to B?

Comment: It's 6 neighbors when the movement is on all 3 axis. I can't really make a 2D diagram that can include A, but think of as I'm trying to project a pyramid inside a cube, where the central point in the base is point B and the vertex is point A.

Comment: Iterating neighbors can probably be done via `for(x-1 .. x+1) { for(y-1 .. y+1) { for (z-1 .. z+1) { /* skip the ones that you don't want */ }}}`. Seen that at least in 2D.

Comment: Said in other words: Point A is the central point of a cube, moving it on one of the axis would impact the central point of a face, moving it on two axis would impact the junction between two faces and moving it on all three axis would impact a corner. I'm interested in the points in the cube that are adjacent (as in no more than +1,+1,+1 or -1,-1,-1) to B, considering that A is at the vertex of the polyhedron being cast on the cube.

Comment: So you want all points adjacent to B on the plane that is perpendicular to A as well as on the line between A and B?  This is hard to visualize, could you attempt to draw what you explained and add pictures?

Comment: Example 1: http://i40.tinypic.com/16iw36v.jpg  Example 2: http://i40.tinypic.com/29wwoig.jpg

Comment: I solved the problem by finding a point C that is the mirror of the point A on B and by looking for all points that are neighboring to A and have a Euclidean distance from C inferior than that of C from A and equal or inferior to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<RPoint> TDNeighborsOnALine(RPoint endPoint){        
    List<RPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Geometry.distanceTwoPoints(this, endPoint) > 1){
        int vx = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (endPoint.getX()-x)));
        int vy = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (endPoint.getY()-y)));
        int vz = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (endPoint.getZ()-z)));
        RPoint b = new RPoint (x + vx, y + vy, z + vz);
        RPoint c = new RPoint (x + (vx*2), y + (vy*2), z + (vz*2));
        for (int ox = -1; ox < 2; ox++){
            for (int oy = -1; oy < 2; oy ++){
                for (int oz = -1; oz < 2; oz++){
                    RPoint p = new RPoint(ox + x, oy + y, oz + z);
                    double d = Geometry.distanceTwoPoints(c, p);
                    if (d < Geometry.distanceTwoPoints(c, this) && d <= 3){
                        points.add(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        points.add(endPoint);
    }
    return points;
}

public static double distanceTwoPoints(RPoint a, RPoint b){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((a.getX() - b.getX()), 2) + Math.pow((a.getY() - b.getY()), 2) + Math.pow((a.getZ() - b.getZ()), 2));
}
```

This is my solution to the problem. It works by relying on the fact that each neighbour to A that is at a lesser distance from C than C is to A, where C is the mirror of A on B, is a point on the path from A to C, each neighbour to A whose distance from C is farther than 3 is not a convenient point on the path either, because it's removed more than x,y,z from C.

Comment: ok, having this further information that you can skip neighbours at certain distance make the part where you must identify the form A-B obsolete - but i was sure, that there would have been much geometry int those 14 forms ^^

Comment: hey - by the way! it was very interesting talking with you and i am wishing you best luck for your further work =) chemistry or moleculary biology or what it may be ^^

Comment: Ahah my degree is in Sociology, I'm writing a game engine as a timewaster :D

Answer (score 1):

i have had to solve such problems on a 2d map (but it's just the same in 3d)

```
public Point[] getNeigbours(Point from, Point to){

    EForm form = determineForm(from, to);
    if (form == EForm.formA){
        Point n1 = new Point(from.x, from.y, from.z+1);
        Point n2 = new Point(from.x, from.y, from.z-1);
        //...and so on
        Point nn = new Point(from.x-1, from.y-1, from.z-1);
        Point[] retValue = new Point[]{n1, n2, ... nn};
        return retValue;
    }

    if (form == EForm.formB){
        Point n1 = // another rule applys for this form
        Point[] retValue = new Point[]{n1, n2, ... nn};
        return retValue;
    }

}

private EForm determineForm(Point from, Point to){
   int dx = to.x-from.x;
   int dy = to.y-from.y;
   int dz = to.x-from.z;

   if (dx == 0 && dx == -1 && dz == 0){
       return EForm.formA;
   }
}
```

so you have first determine the form of you Point-Combination; there should be only 14 possible forms for those two point;

then you have to manually detect all the neighbours for each form; finally if you know them all, you can create your neighbours (using you manually created solutions);

EForm is an Enum, containg those 14 possible forms!

Comment: Unfortunately on 3D it's not so simple because the possibilities are too many to evaluate without a very complex system of switches (and prone to error). I'll still upvote you for answering.

Comment: you have to write a list of 'visited' neighbours; add points, which have been visited into that list. when you get your neighbours, just ask that neighbour is already in this list. if it is not in the list you can continue, else you skip that point.

Comment: You are assuming that the points are neighboring to both points, which, unfortunately, is not the case.

Comment: ah ok, i understand it better now; if A-B is only one&two dimensional (A: 1,1,1 and B: 2,1,1 -> only x-dim changes) (A: 1,1,1 and B: 2,2,1 -> only x&y-dim changes) you have 8 neighbours; if you have three dimensions you have those six neighbours; right?

Comment: ok, 8x6 neighbours, 6x8neighbours - you have to describe 14 forms with a total of 96 possible neigbours, wow, lots of work ^^   but once you have them, you can get ANY neibhours from any combination!

Comment: I added my code that solves the problem, check it out it might help you too :) (it's the same in 2D)